# Enlazar un single.php modificado a un Post Type WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy creando un directorio de Médicos, por lo que usé Custom Post Types y Custom Fields para realizar una ficha personalizada de cada persona que necesitaba para crear un directorio de médicos.

Hasta el momento, hice los custom posts y customs fields, pero segun el tutorial para darle el formato que yo deseo a cada ficha de médico, debo crear una copia del archivo single.php, en el tutorial, le cambia el nombre al archivo, como single-libros.php y automáticamente ya muestra los cambios.

Yo estoy usando Astra, e hice lo que pude para agregar el código, pero no sé si me falta otro paso para conectar los posts del CPT "Médicos" con los campos personalizados, o estoy ingresando mal el código.

[Link de los tutoriales](https://youtu.be/kPSKw4xHs4U)

[image: Custom Post Type "Médicos"]

[image: Custom fields activados]

[image: Los campos no son mostrados]

single-doctor.php:

```
 <?php
/**
* The template for displaying all single posts.
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
*
* @package Astra
* @since 1.0.0
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'left-sidebar' ) : ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif ?>

    <div id="primary" <?php astra_primary_class(); ?>>

        <?php astra_primary_content_top(); ?>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <?php $imagen_doctor = get_field( 'imagen_doctor' ); ?>
      <?php if ( $imagen_doctor ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imagen_doctor['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $imagen_doctor['alt']; ?>" />
<?php } ?> </br></br>

      <b>Nombre:</b> &nsbp; <?php the_field( 'nombre' ); ?></br></br>

         <b>Especialidad:</b>&nsbp;<?php the_field( 'especialidad' ); ?></br></br>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <i><?php the_field( 'resena' ); ?></i><br></br>
        <b>Permiso COFEPRIS:</b>&nsbp;<?php the_field( 'permiso_cofepris' ); ?></br></br>
        <b>Cédula Profesional:</b>&nsbp;<?php the_field( 'cedula' ); ?></br></br>
        <b>Dirección:</b>&nsbp;<?php the_field( 'direccion' ); ?></br></br>
        <b>Teléfono:</b>&nsbp;<?php the_field( 'telefono' ); ?></br></br>
        <b>Correo Electrónico:</b>&nsbp;<?php the_field( 'correo' ); ?></br></br>
        <?php $location_array = get_field( 'ubicacion_google_maps' );
// var_dump( $location_array ); ?></br></br>
        </div>

        <?php astra_content_loop(); ?>


        <?php astra_primary_content_bottom(); ?>

    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'right-sidebar' ) : ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es: Únicamente hay que cambiar el nombre del archivo al mismo que el custom post type para que lo reconozca.

Yo usaba single-doctores.php pero el nombre del custom post type era "Pt_doctores" por eso no aparecía y tenía conflictos; así que cambié el nombre del archivo a ´single-pt_doctores.php´ y ahora funciona correctamente.